# How to remove the text style after clicking on outside of div section using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide

```
<style type='text/css'>
.active {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>`
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 pt-5">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a id="navLink" data-toggle="pill" href="#development" role="tab"
                       aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Web Development</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a id="navLink" data-toggle="pill" href="#appsgamedevelopment" role="tab"
                       aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Apps and game development</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a id="navLink" data-toggle="pill" href="#graphicsdesign" role="tab"
                       aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Graphics Design</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
</div>
```

Now i m going to show you the js

```
var navLink = document.getElementById("navLink");

$("#pills-tabContent").hide();

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).closest('.nav-item').length ) {
        $("#pills-tabContent").show();
    }else if ( ! $(e.target).closest('#pills-tabContent').length ) {
        navLink.className = navLink.className.replace(/\bactive\b/g, "");
        navLink.className = navLink.className.replace(/\bshow\b/g, "");
        $('#pills-tabContent').hide();
    }
});
```

I want to remove the class and it should be also work on IE. In here I am only facing problem with 'active' class others are working fine. 
Example: When I click on 'web development' 'active' class perfectly working. and when I click on outside of div then active class remove. 
But when I click on 'apps and game development' 'active' class perfectly working. But when I am clicking on outside of div then it's not removing the 'active' class.

Now I am literally confused what's the problem and how to do code for this.

Thank you.

Comment: You have a bunch of links with an ID of "navLink". There are not supposed to be more than one element with the same ID on the same page. You call document.getElementById("navLink") once at the beginning of your script -- this will always refer to the first element with that ID, in this case the "Web Development" link. Maybe this can get you started towards a solution.

Comment: yah i know for this reason I need to make a loop. But I tried nothing happening. :( sad life @klumme

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("navLink");` will always return only one element. Rather add class and then use `document.getElementsByClassName("xyz")`.

Best option would be to use Jquery.
`$('#navLink').removeClass('active').removeClass('show');`

Comment: is it suitable for IE9.

Comment: Yes, ideally this should work on IE 9. As, IE 9 supports className API which is used in both solution mentioned above. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

Comment: it's still the same. I think I need to make it loop but I tried output 0. @nishant

Comment: Did you tried this? $('#navLink').removeClass('active').removeClass('show'); @ArafHossain

Comment: Can you host your code somewhere and give me the link? Preferably repl

Comment: Give me some time.